# Identify the plant

Tags: identification

Recently I bought a cute little plant and the man said it is a succulent plant. This is my first time taking care of succulent plant so I would like to study about it. Could someone please identify the plant?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a Sedum, Sedum acre 'aureum' or a similar yellow leaved variety. It is a ground cover plant for the front of a border or bed; it prefers full sun and copes well with dry soil. Usually covered in small, bright yellow flowers in spring, can be invasive if it likes its situation https://www.swiftgreenhouses.com/plant/Sedum-Acre-Aurea